# How to deconvolve a step function from a time-series signal

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, convolution, wavelet

I want to remove a step (jump, Heaviside) function from a time series data, as shown in the picture. Could anyone give some hints (or references) on how to do this?

The link to the image is :
[Multichannel signal convolved with heaviside functions](http://liubenyuan.github.io/pics/new.png)

[image: Linked Image]

One sample channel dataset is available at:
[Sample, one Channel of the dataset](http://liubenyuan.github.io/pics/new.csv)

Comment: I have added the linked image on your behalf.

Comment: @SteveBarnes thanks ! I updated the link with a single channel data.

Comment: Out of interest, what kind of source is generating the signal? :)

Comment: Second link is dead?

Comment: This is not a step function and what you need is a **low pass filter**, you are missing code of what you have tried and do not rely on external links in you question.

Answer (score 0):

Since convolution is the multiplication in frequency domain deconvolution should be division. The fourier transform of the heaviside is 1/jw, so you would want to divide with this (ie multiply with jw). Now the inverse fourier transform of jw is the derivative of the dirac distribution. So you should convolute with the derivative of the dirac distribution.

In the discrete case the derivative of it is `1` for `k=0` and `-1` for `k=1` and zero elsewhere

```
def deconv(seq):
    prev = 0
    for cur in seq:
        yield cur - prev
        prev = cur
```

I see no reason why the result shouldn't be unique.

Comment: but the time shift, as well as the number of Heaviside function is unknown, i.e., u_i(t-tau).

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question, but of course then the result is not unique. You will end up with a unknown timeshift. Without further information it will remain unknown.

Comment: I am sorry for the missing information. I updated the post and add one time series of sample signals. Thanks anyway!